# Set different value and label for Check Component on Pentaho CDE

Tags: javascript, pentaho, pentaho-cde, pentaho-ctools

I am retrieving data from a datasource like this:

```
 VALUE | LABEL
-------+-----------
 'ES'  | 'Spain'
 'IT'  | 'Italy'
 'FR'  | 'France'
  ...  |  ...
```

I want my Check Component to show values on the **label** column, but use values on the **value** column instead as the component's own Parameter's value, so if a user selects 'Spain', my `countries` parameter adds `'ES'` to the list of countries. It has to end up being something like this:

```
<input ... value="ES">
<label ...>Spain</label>
```

<strike>So far, I know if I provide a static list on the `Values array` property for the component, this will work</strike>. But I can't figure out how to achieve the same thing via my dynamic datasource.

Please don't suggest to hack it after rendering with some jQuery or the like, I want to know if Pentaho CDE provides a way to do this properly.

**Update:** Providing a static list won't work. No matter what you put on the `Arg` and `Value` columns, only the `Value` will be used. But I found out why, and I wrote the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, just in case someone falls into the same dumb mistake.

There is an option for the component, called `Value as Id`. When set as `false`, provided there are two columns on the datasource for this component, the first column will be used as `value` for the checkbox input, and the second column will be used as text for the `label` element.

So my original dataset worked when I set `Value as Id` as `false`.